# Hello do i'm trying to code a powershell script that upload and overwrite a folder to an other folder

Tags: powershell, ftp

So I'm basically new to powershell coding and I don't really know if I'm doing this right - just started a few days ago.

My main goal is to send a folder to a ftp server and overwrite the folder that's already on the server due to daily upload. Sorry but I'm a bit of a nerd and would like a few recommendations if I'm doing this well or not. Thank you

I tried to code something using powershell and a batch file .
And it actually work's but localy on my pc ( copy the folder and paste it in wanted folder) But it just won't work when trying to do this on a remote ftp server that's saved on my pc.

script:

```
[string]$sourceDirectory  = "C:\test\*"
[string]$destinationDirectory = "C:\Users\c0ld\Desktop/receive "
Copy-item -Force -Recurse -Verbose $sourceDirectory -Destination $destinationDirectory
exit
```

Bat script:

```
@ECHO OFF
PowerShell.exe -Command "& 'C:/test.ps1'"
PAUSE
```

So this works when working on actual local folder, but when trying to do this on a network FTP folder it's actually not working.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have the correct permissions to access the server.
Then remember(this got me a couple times) that instead of c:\path, you would use the admin share to access a remote pc, which is \remotecomputer\c$\path.

Comment: So i didn't really been precise on this , sorry , but the ftp server is hosted on a non local server . it's just added as a network location folder . Is this advice still good for non local ftp server ? Thank you .

Comment: @c0ld then you will just use the network location path, you do not need to worry about the admin share.

Comment: So if im right , this is the same as uploading to the ftp server ? without needing to use ftp commands to connect to it ect . Because ftp server is already saved to my pc ?